# Is there a way to warn me Global Namespace Pollutions?

Tags: c++, namespaces, warnings

Does gcc (or any other compiler) have an option to warn me global namespace pollutions?

I tried to compile a sample application suite, but it turned out quite a few of header files of that samples are stricken with global namespace pollutions (*`using namespace`* in header files), so that Mac OS X global struct Rect becomes ambiguous.
I also tried to change the order of #include to resolve the system's Rect symbol before the minefield of *`using namespace`*, but that caused some symbols end up not resolved.

My earlier search using Google failed, bad premonition though, if that kind of warning option exists, please give me info.

Comment: search and delete - these problems usually persist/return until removed.

Comment: @Justin: Problem is, there may be instances of `using namespace` that aren't in the global namespace.

Comment: @Potatoswatter i didn't *intend* to imply that every `using` declaration should be deleted; only the global ones (the subject of the OP).

Comment: @Justin @Potatoswatter About 75 instances of `using namespace` in 34 sample applications are seemingly problematic (not a small amount of source code). I know I have to deal with it myself to get rid of them. But, if a warning option I described exists, developers themselves become cautious about `using namespace` at global scope, and mental labor I'll have to go through for this can be avoided. *sigh*

Comment: @Shigerello i understand the problem and avoid many common uses of `using`, and i realize that my comment was not a direct answer to your question (indirect, if no suitable answer is given for your programs). if you're targeting osx, then Matthieu M.'s response should do the trick if your programs are compatible with clang at this time. if i'd know the flag existed, that's the answer i'd have left.

Comment: [Global Warning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_warming) - a growing concern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about gcc, but CLang has it:

```
def warn_using_directive_in_header : Warning<
  "using namespace directive in global context in header">,
  InGroup<HeaderHygiene>, DefaultIgnore;
```

You can activate it directly using `-Wusing-directive-in-header` or via the group `-Wheader-hygiene` (it is, for now, the sole member of the group).

It's been thoroughly reviewed on the mailing list and normally does not warn about regular cases.

Comment: Hmm, looks like this warning option was introduced recently. These warning option did not work for "Apple clang version 2.0" and gcc-4.2.1 for Xcode 4.0.1 (/Developer/usr/bin/clang and such). I expect the same for Xcode 3.2. But definitely a delightful feature. Should be incorporated to gcc.

Comment: @Shigerello: it is recent, I am not even sure it is present in the latest CLang release (2.9).